# how to use Ui-TinyMCE onchange event

Tags: angularjs, tinymce-4

How to use ui-tinymce's onchange event?.
I am using following code, but it is not working

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    onChange: function(e) {
        console.log('onchange:');
    },
    inline: true,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: "bold italic underline styleselect",
    statusbar: false
};
```

Is the above code right or should I modify it? I want to perform some action when there is some editing done on tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did some quick testing and didn't get the `onChange` function to fire either.

I don't know `ui-tinymce` or why it isn't working, but I took a look at the source code and whatever you put in `tinymceOptions` will be passed on to the tinymce instance.

So find how you are supposed to do it in the TinyMCE version you are using and use that.

For example:

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
  setup: function(e) {

    e.on('change', function () {

      console.log('change');
    });

    e.on('redo', function () {

      console.log('redo');
    });

    e.on('undo', function () {

      console.log('undo');
    });
  },
  inline: false,
  plugins: 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview',
  skin: 'lightgray',
  theme: 'modern'
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/3nOtD7Cw0wc3mmBx0vqc?p=preview